# How to get all displayed img elements quickly in selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to write a common parser for shopify-collection page, just to extract all the list goods imgs, like  https://www.michaelstars.com/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling

As every site has it's own layout and javascripts, I have written some selenium code to auto render the page,
I have written some code to detect the big img show in the page.

```
    for ele in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//img'):
        if ele.is_displayed():
            size = ele.size
            print size
            if size['width'] > 50:
                info = {
                    'src': ele.get_attribute('src'),
                    'class': ele.get_attribute('class'),
                    'size': ele.size,
                    'location': ele.location,
                }
                img_elements.append(info)
```

But the detect code runs very slow, I want know if it is possible to make the detect code run faster.

Answer (score 0):

1. try following css selector instead of xpath

for ele in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".pi__main-images"):

2. Instead of checking is_displayed() every time in loop use Explicit waits for elements it can save time.

Comment: find_elements_by_xpath runs quite fast, less than 0.1s,  I have check with code      print len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//img'))     ，  I can not explicit for specific elements because it is common parser for thousands of sites, every site may be different... Thank you all the same.